# Custom Angular validator with parameters only runs once

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a custom validator with parameters set on a `FormGroup` and it is running once when initialized but is not being triggered on any of the control changes. Removing the parameters runs the validator on each control change but obviously doesn't work without the parameters. Any suggestions to getting this to run on each control change? I've tried to watch the controls and use `updateValueAndValidity()` and still have no luck.

```js
const customValidator = (options: { min: number, max: number }): ValidatorFn => {
  console.log(options);
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    // logic returning null or { 'not-enough': true }
  }
}
    
this.form = new FormGroup({
  controlOne: new FormControl(null),
  controlTwo: new FormControl(null)
}, { validators: [customValidator({min: 5, max: 10})]});
```

### Found Solution

Thanks to comments below and other answers I realized that my console logs outside for the return function of the validator only run once. Moving that and any other additional logic inside of the return function, runs as expected. Ultimately my solution was just moving some code down a line...

```js
const customValidator = (options: { min: number, max: number }): ValidatorFn => {
  // No code up here will run on each control being validated
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    // code down here will run on every control change
    // logic returning null or { 'not-enough': true }
  }
}
    
this.form = new FormGroup({
  controlOne: new FormControl(null),
  controlTwo: new FormControl(null)
}, { validators: [customValidator({min: 5, max: 10})]});
```

Comment: any errors in your console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console.The issue is the validator only runs once when the form instance is created. I'm looking to run the validator anytime a control within the form group changes.

Comment: Seems to work just fine in this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-custom-validation-gcbyvt. Are you doing anything different?

Comment: Yes thank you, I found the issue. I had some object de-structuring of the `options` params above `return` along with my console logs. I see the factory runs once but the validator is everything in the return function. I moved my logic inside of the return function and all is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an error in the console because you're not returning anything in your `ValidatorFn`:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(13,44): error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

#### Template

1. Be sure to bind the `FormGroup` to the form
2. Be sure to bind every `FormControl`

Code

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="text" formControlName="controlOne">
      <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

#### Module

1. be sure to import the `ReactiveFormsModule`

Code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### Controller

1. import `FormControl, FormGroup, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn`
2. return from the `ValidatorFn`

Code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    customValidator = (options: { min: number, max: number }): ValidatorFn => {
        return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
            console.log(options.min, options.max);
            return {};//RETURN ERRORS HERE
        }
    }

    form = new FormGroup({
        controlOne: new FormControl(null)
    }, { validators: [this.customValidator({min: 5, max: 10})]});
}
```

Comment: I excluded all of that for brevity...doesn't fix the problem that the validator only runs once when the form instance is created not on each control change value change.In your example you have a `console.log` if you were to actually run your solution you would see the validator only hit once and `console.log` only output to the console once.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question then. This validator runs whenever the controls in the FormGroup *change.* Is that not the intended functionality?

Comment: The ValidatorFnFactory will of course only run once if that is what you're referring to.

Comment: *Any suggestions to getting this to run on each control change?* Maybe I don't understand what *this* is. Are talking about the custom validator factory or the validator returned from it? The latter works already, so you must be referring to the former... Is that correct?

Comment: I was under the assumption that the `customValidator` function would run each time a control within the form group changes either returning an error or null. Is this not the case? This is my first time writing a custom validator so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I found the issue, thinking through what you mentioned and the above comments to my question, If found that everything outside of the return function only runs once. I moved my logs and some other variables inside the return function and all works as expected.

Comment: That is correct. The `customValidator` function is actually a *factory* function. When you called it with `customValidator({min: 5, max: 10})`, it returned the `ValidatorFn`. Whatever is in the returned ValidatorFn will execute on each FormControl change.

Comment: Great thank you, I've edited the question to also include these notes for future viewers.

Comment: You have to acknowledge that your initial comment on my answer was incorrect. The `console.log` I provided applied on *every* change. The solution I provided you was correct and complete.